# Parse Javascript Object

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, dropzone.js

I am using dropzone.js to upload files via ajax but I need to implement a fallback method for older browsers that don't support XMLHttpRequest.

To work around this I'm using the [jQuery Iframe Transport plugin](https://cmlenz.github.io/jquery-iframe-transport/)

```
 $.ajax({
        url: "/File/Create",
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        data: { fallback: true },
        files: $("form :file"),
        iframe: true,
        processData: false
   }).complete(function (data) {
        console.log(data.message);

    });
```

As the jquery iframe transport does not have access to the HTTP headers of the server response, it is not as simple to make use of the automatic content type detection provided by jQuery as with regular XHR.

A workaround is to send back an HTML document containing just a `<textarea>` element with a data-type attribute that specifies the MIME type, and put the actual payload in the textarea:

```
<textarea data-type="application/json">
   {"ok": true, "message": "Thanks so much"}
</textarea>
```

So in my asp mvc controller I return the response as follows:

```
if (fallback == "true")
{
    return Content("<textarea data-type=\"application/json\">{\"ok\": false, \"message\": \"Success.\"}</textarea>");

}
```

Which returns the following javascript object:

```
Object { readyState=4, responseText="{"ok": false, "message": "Success"}", responseJSON Object {ok=false, message="Success"}
```

How do I parse this response to output the Json message. The following gives me undefined?

```
.complete(function (data) {
        console.log(data.message);
});
```

Comment: try adding dataType:"json" in the request

Comment: just send valid JSON format. it will work

Comment: @Ashish I can't as I'm using jquery-iframe-transport

Comment: Why? That library is massively outdated. If you want to upload files use `FormData`. Then you can actually return JSON directly instead of having to use a fudge of a workaround

Comment: You should also consider a implementing a [FileSizeAttribute](http://www.bradwestness.com/2014/09/24/client-side-file-upload-validation/) to give you client and server side validation

Comment: @Rory I'm using dropzone.js but I need to implement a fallback method for older browsers

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan the whole point of it is for browsers that don't support that. all of which now happen to be no longer maintained by their owners.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. just needed to do the following:

```
console.log(data.responseJSON.message);
```